# Font-face Flicker Firefox FadeIn

Tags: jquery, firefox, font-face

In Firefox, when using jQuery to fadeIn a div

It seems to cause text using a font-face to flicker?

One way to stop the flickering is for the text to be a certain distance from the fade.

Why on earth would this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/6q2KP/ . Do you have a specific example?

Comment: It's not actually specifically due to the fadeIn actually. It seems if a background-image fadesIn it causes the flicker.

Comment: Either way, a specific example with code would help.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had issues with fading in text based elements in IE - regardless of font-face. While not applicable at all scenarios, we got around the issue by fading out and removing an absolutely positioned `<div>` with the same background colour as the background colour of the text.

The ideal solution was not to use FadeIn for text - which is hard to explain to your clients or designer colleagues ;-)